# R dplyr - Sum values for different factors

Tags: r, dplyr

I have multiple factors ("a","b","c") in my dataset, each with corresponding values for Price and Cost.

```
dat <- data.frame(
 ProductCode = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c"), 
 Price = c(24, 37, 78, 45, 20, 34),
 Cost = c(10,15,45,25,10,17)
)
```

I am looking for the sum of Price and Cost for each ProductCode.

```
by.code <- group_by(dat, code)
by.code <- summarise(by.code, 
                        SumPrice = sum(Price),
                        SumCost = sum(Cost))
```

This code does not work as it sums all values in the column, without breaking them into categories.

```
  SumPrice SumCost
1      238     122
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You might have a function name conflict with plyr. Try your code with `dplyr::summarise(...)`

Answer (score 1):

This is not dplyr - This answer is for you if you dont mind the `sqldf` or `data.table` package:

```
sqldf("select ProductCode, sum(Price) as PriceSum, sum(Cost) as CostSum from dat group by ProductCode")

ProductCode PriceSum CostSum
       a       61      25
       b      123      70
       c       54      27
```

**OR** using the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
MM<-data.table(dat)
MM[, list(sum(Price),sum(Cost)), by = ProductCode]

ProductCode  V1 V2
1:           a  61 25
2:           b 123 70
3:           c  54 27
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine. There was just a typo. You should name your column ProductionCode into code and your code works fine. I just did that and R is giving proper output. Below is the code:

```
library(dplyr)
dat <- data.frame(
 code = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c"), 
 Price = c(24, 37, 78, 45, 20, 34),
 Cost = c(10,15,45,25,10,17)
)
dat
by.code <- group_by(dat, code)
by.code <- summarise(by.code, 
                        SumPrice = sum(Price),
                        SumCost = sum(Cost))
by.code
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I tried this code - it still doesn't work. Are you sure it gave you the proper output?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(.~ProductCode, dat, sum)
#   ProductCode Price Cost
#1           a    61   25
#2           b   123   70
#3           c    54   27
```